# using find but only in subdirectories matching certain pattern

Tags: linux, find

I am trying to construct my etags file. I have a project structure such that given a root directory there are subdirectories and within those can be directories named 'cpp'. For example:

```
root
 - sub1
  - cpp
 - sub2
  - sub21
   - cpp
   - csharp
```

So for regular project i usually something like:
find . -type f ( -iname '*.cpp' -o -iname '*.hpp' -o -iname '*.c' -o -iname '*.h' -o -iname '*.cc' -o -iname '*.hh' ) -print | xargs etags -a

This won't work anymore as it will also pick up files that could be csharp, objective c etc...

So what i am trying to accomplish is to only have find return the files in the subdirectories called cpp. So how can i get find to do that?

Thanks ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nested `find` might work for you

```
find . -type d -name "cpp" -exec find {} -type f \;
```

Answer (score 7):

Or more simply (assuming there are not further subdirectories in the cpp directories:

```
find . -type f -path "*/cpp/*"
```

This would return the whole relative path from . though, which may require further trimming :/